# Minecraft PE testforblocks else

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I need to check that at front of car at height of 1 block there is at least one block except air. This is necessary so that car can overcome obstacles while driving. When I do this by checking air 0 and red torches, car sometimes flies up 1 block due to fact that delay is too long. Test of the off comparator from command unit also gives a large delay. Are there any ways to implement else in command blocks without redstone torches/comparators, or with minimum delay?

Comment: Just don't use redstone with command blocks. "else" is usually implemented by giving a tag and then checking for the absence of that tag. I recommend watching/reading a commands tutorial, for example Slicedlime has a good one.

Comment: Minecraft Bedrock Edition don't have NBT tags in commands!

Comment: I mean scoreboard tags.

Comment: /scoreboard - Java Edition only

Comment: What version of Minecraft are you on?

Comment: 1.2.11.4 version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was solved by command /testforblocks: I connect to a cyclic command block -  chain command block with empty command and with "if", and in another place I put an chain command command block with empty command and " if", connected to cyclic command block with always wrong if, and when the command block tester detects the coincidence of these two blocks - it gives an impulse to chain and car ride.
Sorry for bad english, please fix my answer